# find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid yelling about ActiveRecord owning "create"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, omniauth

I'm implementing twitter/facebook OAuth login via this railscasts episode here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

I'm using the code from the Omniauth README at github:

```
  def oauthing
    auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    current_user.authentications.find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])
    flash[:notice] = "Authentication Successful"
    redirect_to '/'
  end
```

And it throws an error about the method "create" belonging to ActiveRecord. Now, I can get the code above to work if I delete "_or_create", but now I can only use Twitter/Facebook OAuth to authenticate *existing* users, and not create new ones.

I've Googled around like crazy, but with no success. How can I make this work so I can create accounts via Omniauth instead of just authenticating?

Answer (score 0):

Split the query and try :

```
is_user = current_user.authentications.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])

current_user.authentications.create(:provider => auth['provider'], :uid => auth['uid']) if is_user.nil?
```

Comment: Nope, still getting the {ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError in AuthenticationController#oauthing

create is defined by ActiveRecord}